# Xcode 4: How to add custom GCC compiler arguments?

Tags: xcode

I'm building a C++ project, how do I add a custom compiler argument that Xcode doesn't have? Like -fwide-exec-charset=UCS-2LE. I searched on the internet but only found the solution to xcode 3.x. I'm using Xcode 4.5.2 and the UI is too different.

PS. It's NOT the commandline argument which used when debugging program, it's the g++ compiler argument which used when compiling the source codes.

Comment: I think you are looking for ["Other C++ Flags"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003931-CH3-SW19) under your target's settings.

Comment: Thanks! But -fwide-exec-charset=UCS-2LE doesn't seem to work, I also tried -fwide-exec-charset=UTF-16, still the same. Maybe I'll start a new thread...